# Rails: join across two columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm building a dating app, and I'm creating a table (and model) for when users rate each other (like/dislike). I'm supporting multiple genders, so I don't want to simply have columns for "man's ID" and "woman's ID". However, that means I simply have two users IDs, and need to search both for the current user's ID.

I've managed to get the migration to work, but not to get the actual class to work. I can't figure out how to tell Rails to search both columns.

Ratings migration:

```
class CreateRatings < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :ratings do |t|
      t.references :event, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user1, index: true, null: false, foreign_key: {to_table: :users}
      t.references :user2, index: true, null: false, foreign_key: {to_table: :users}

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Ratings model:

```
class Rating < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user1, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :user2, class_name: "User"
end
```

When I try it in irb, I get:

```
irb(main):003:0> User.first.ratings
  User Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column ratings.user_id does not exist)
LINE 1: SELECT "ratings".* FROM "ratings" WHERE "ratings"."user_id" ...
                                                ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "ratings.user1_id" or the column "ratings.user2_id".
irb(main):004:0>
```

**Does this just need to be left out of Rails association-land?** e.g. Should I instead define a method in the User class to get records matching `Ratings.user1=User.id OR Ratings.user2=User.id`?

I'm using a Postgres database, if that allows any cool solutions.

---

Users migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.string :email, null: false
      <snip>

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true
  end
end
```

Users model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ratings
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not specify a foreign key, a default user_id will be looked for, but it does not exist, hence the error message you are getting. So you can do:

```
class Rating < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user1, class_name: "User", :foreign_key => 'user1' 
  belongs_to :user2, class_name: "User", :foreign_key => 'user2'
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ratings1, foreign_key: :user1, class_name: 'Rating'
  has_many :ratings2, foreign_key: :user2, class_name: 'Rating'
end
```

Then you can do

`user.ratings1.first` and `user.ratings2.first`

To display both, you need a method like:

```
def all_user_ratings
  Rating.where("user1 = ? OR user2 = ?", user.id, user.id)
end
```

Comment: So my supposition of "this isn't possible in a Rails association" was right, ok, thank you! I'll use that method you wrote :)

Comment: Yes you need to use a method to display both :)

Comment: also  `Rating.where(":user in (user1, user2)", user: user.id)`, `Rating.where(user1: user.id).or(Rating.where(user2: user.id))`